# Subset sums and conditions

Tags: combinatorics

For a given $n$-element set $N$, how can I find all $r$-element subsets of $N$ such that sum of all elements of $r$ is: $(i)$ less than  $a$ $(ii)$ greater than $a$ $(iii)$ equal to $a$ ?

Further show that number of subsets holding property $(i)$ is less than number of subsets holding property $(ii)$ and $(iii)$ together.

---

I'm looking for a purely Mathematical (combinatorial) approach for this, instead of dynamic programming. I've tried in two ways but in vain: $(i)$ to eliminate excess subsets from total number of sets $(ii)$ show an injection which is not a surjection.

Comment: Hi. $N$ has to have some boundaries because suppose $a=6$ and $N=\{1,2,3\}$, there is just $1$ subset that sums equal or greater than $a$ and the remaining $7$ sum less than $a$.

Comment: @Phicar: Isn't there any way to represent it in a generalized form, ie. number of possible subsets expressed in terms of $n$, $r$, and $a$ ?

Comment: Here's the original problem if someone wants an example: Show that the number of 3−element subsets $(a, b, c)$ of the set $ S= (1, 2, 3, . . . , 63)$ with $a + b + c < 95$ is less than the number of those with $a + b + c \geq 95$. (INMO 1995)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the following.

I’m afraid that, in general, there is no simple approach which is essentially better than a brute-force check of all $r$-element subsets of $N$.  The problems of such type usually are hard to deal, and the problem to calculate all sums of the subsets of a given $n$-element set is even NP-complete.

Of course, there can be some estimations, especially, for some particular cases. For instance, the number from the original problem has simple geometric interpretation a number $I(T)$ of all integer points inside a tetrahedron $$T=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R^3:a,b,c\ge 1\mbox{ and }a+b+c\le 94\}$$ is approximately equal to the volume $V(T)$ of $T$. More precisely, $$(89)^2/6=V(T^-)\le I(T)\le V(T^+)=(95)^2/6,$$ where $V(T^-)$ and $V(T^-)$ are volumes of the tetrahedrons $$T^-=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R^3:a,b,c\ge 1\mbox{ and }a+1+b+1+c+1\le 95\}$$ and $$T^+=\{(a,b,c)\in\mathbb R^3:a,b,c\ge 1\mbox{ and }a-1+b-1+c-1\le 95\},$$ respectively.

But the solution of the original problem is a lot more easier, even simple. Indeed, consider a bijection $f:\{a,b,c\}\to \{64-a,64-b,64-c\}$ of the family $[N]_3$ of all 3-element subsets of the set $N$. Then the family $[N]_3$ is partitioned into two families: a family $[N]_{30}$ of fixed points of the map $f$ (which have a form $\{32,x,64-x\}$ for some $x\in S$, so $|[N]_{30}|=31$) and a family $[N]_{31}$ of non-fixed points of the map $f$. Moreover, the family $[N]_{31}$ is partitioned into pairs $\{A=f(f(A)), f(A)\}$. For each 3-element subset $A$ of the set $N$ as $S(A)$ we denote the sum of the elements of the set $A$. Now if $S(A)<95$ then $S(A)<S(f(A))=196-S(A)$ so $A \ne f(A)$ and $A\in [N]_{31}$. It folows that the number of 3-elements subsets A of $N$ with $S(A)<95$ is not greater than $|[N]_{31}|/2<|[N]_{3}|/2$.